# SQL - Update not working inside a cursor loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have three tables namely `Issue`, `IssueReports` and `Location` with the below structure.

Issue and Location has Many-to-one relationship. Issue and IssueReports are not physically linked but can have some common fields.

```
IssueReports
-------------
ID (Number); 
Issue_Number (Varchar); 
Issue_Loc_Name (Varchar)
and some other fields for the report....

Issue
-----------------
ID (Number);
IssueNumber (Varchar);
Issue_Loc_Id (Number)

Location
-----------------
ID (Number);
Loc_Name (Varchar)
```

I want to update `Issue_Loc_Name` field in multiple rows of `IssueReports` with `Loc_Name` where the `IssueNumber` of Issue table and `IssueNumber` of `IssueReport` table are equal.

I have written the below procedure to update multiple records based on the condition given above, but what I get is the same value for all the `Issue_Loc_name` of multiple rows of the table `IssueReport`.

```
DECLARE
   IR_LOCNAME    VARCHAR2(10);
   IRNUM_TO_SEARCH VARCHAR2(10);
   ISNUM_TOSEARCH VARCHAR2(10);
   Cursor c1 is select ir.Issue_Number, is.IssueNumber, loc.loc_name
    from IssueReports ir, Issue is, Location loc
    where loc.id = is.Issue_Loc_Id
                AND ir.Issue_Number = is.IssueNumber;      
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO IRNUM_TO_SEARCH, ISNUM_TOSEARCH, IR_LOCNAME;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(IRNUM_TO_SEARCH || ' ' || ISNUM_TOSEARCH || ' ' || IR_LOCNAME);
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      UPDATE IssueReports SET Issue_Loc_Name = IR_LOCNAME;
             WHERE IRNUM_TO_SEARCH = ISNUM_TOSEARCH;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE C1;
END;
/
```

Is there something wrong in my cursor? I am using Oracle 11G.

Best Regards,
MouliPC.

Comment: You probably don't need a loop at all - a single UPDATE or MERGE might be enough. Doing row-by-row processing is almost always the wrong way to do things in a relational database. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This is indeed the useful hint. I could complete the update using a single MERGE statement. Thank you. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could complete the update using MERGE with the below query.

```
MERGE INTO IssueReport IR using 
           (select ir.Issue_Number as irin, 
               is.IssueNumber as isin, 
               loc.loc_name as location 
            from IssueReports ir, 
                 Issue is, 
                 Location loc 
            where loc.id = is.Issue_Loc_Id AND ir.Issue_Number = is.IssueNumber) result 
       ON (is.issue_number = result.isin) 
WHEN MATCHED then update set Issue_Loc_Name = result.location;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
  UPDATE IssueReports SET Issue_Loc_Name = IR_LOCNAME;
         WHERE IRNUM_TO_SEARCH = ISNUM_TOSEARCH;
```

If your two local variables `IRNUM_TO_SEARCH` and `ISNUM_TO_SEARCH` happen to be equal, the entire table will be updated. Otherwise, no rows will be updated.

Did you perhaps mean to write the following?

```
  UPDATE IssueReports SET Issue_Loc_Name = IR_LOCNAME;
         WHERE IssueNumber = ISNUM_TOSEARCH;
```

Comment: I tried the above solution, but ended up with the same result. See my answer below, that did the trick actually.